# Get user input for drawingpanel and use it in another method

Tags: java, methods, user-input

I am very new to java and I need a little help on a an assignment. The assignment was to get user input (radius, x-coordinate, & y-coordinate) to draw 3 different colored circles in a drawingPanel, I have that part down. The second part asks us for a static method that compares the radii of two circles and lets the user know if one is smaller, bigger, or the same size as the other. I am having trouble figuring out how to use the input for the radii in the method that compares the two.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Circles {
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);  


  public static void blueCircle(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    int r = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int x = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int y = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    g.fillOval(0 + x, 0 + y, r * 2, r * 2); 
  }
  public static void greenCircle(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    int r = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int x = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int y = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    g.fillOval(0 + x, 0 + y, r * 2, r * 2); 
  }
  public static void redCircle(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    int r = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int x = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    int y = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    g.fillOval(0 + x, 0 + y, r * 2, r * 2); 

  }
   public static void compareCircles(int r1, int r2) {
    int x;
    if (r1 < r2)
      x = -1;
    if (r1 == r2)
      x = 0;
    if (r1 > r2)
      x = 1;
    return;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 300);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    System.out.println("Enter values for the radius, x , & y-coordinates of blue circle: ");
    blueCircle(g);
    System.out.println("Enter values for the radius, x , & y-coordinates of green circle: ");
    greenCircle(g);
    System.out.println("Enter values for the radius, x , & y-coordinates of red circle: ");
    redCircle(g);

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the code reuse in your implementation. Make a generic method for create the circle for given input parameters.

```
public static void blueCircle(Graphics g, int r, int x, int y, Color c) {
    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillOval(0 + x, 0 + y, r * 2, r * 2); 
}
```

Then one generic method for radii comparison.

```
public static String compareCircles(int r1, int r2) {  
       String output = "";
       if (r1 < r2)
           output = r1+" circle is smaller than "+r2;
       if (r1 == r2)
           output = "both circles are in same size.";
       if (r1 > r2)
           output = r1+" circle is larger than "+r2;
       return output;
}
```

Now within the main mehod get the necessary inputs and pass them to these methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 300);
   Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
   System.out.println("Enter values for the radius, x , & y-coordinates of blue circle: ");
   int rBlue = CONSOLE.nextInt();
   int xBlue = CONSOLE.nextInt();
   int yBlue = CONSOLE.nextInt();
   // Better to do the validation for the user inputs 
   blueCircle(g, rBlue, xBlue, yBlue, Color.BLUE);
   // Do the same thing for the other two circles. 
   // Then call the comparison method with your r input values like below.
   //String output = compareCircles(rBlue, rGreen);
```

}

Hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: What should I do if I have to compare each circle to one another by calling the comparison method 3 times.  Ex: compareCircles(rb,rg);    
  compareCircles (rb,rr);    compareCircles(rr,rg);

Comment: You have to call the comaparison function 3 times after yo create 3 circles as you mentioned in above comment